# I need a word which means “not bound by time or space”

Tags: single-word-requests

**I need a single word which means "not bound by time or space"**

Words such as "timeless," "eternal," "atemporal," ",forever," or "incorporal" either means "not bound by time" or "not bound by space" but I need a word means both.

---

**Here is what I am writing:**

Either way, regardless of how powerful we, humans, become or how technologically advanced we will be, or how much knowledge we will accumulate, the concern which will forever haunt humanity is still the same: *how will we, humans, put our power to use?* We could even invent the time machine today. We could discover the secret to teleportation today. We could all move to Mars today. We could produce a weapon that is even more destructive than a nuclear bomb today. And none of that would answer how humans ought to put these great tools to use. Here, the more powerful humans become the more we are prone to causing our own destruction. Power is something which none of us should take likely. The question of how we ought to use our power is a crucial question which humanity must answer and must answer correctly. Regardless of how powerful or powerless we are, regardless of what context we might find ourselves in—from talking to our loved ones all the way to making a decision that could affect millions, regardless of whether it would be right at this very moment or ten thousand years from now, there is just not a time nor space which this question isn’t relevant.

The purpose of my research aims to solve and answer this [**A WORD WHICH MEANS NOT BOUND BY TIME OR SPACE HERE**] question.

---

**PLEASE DO NOT GET INTO A PHILOSOPHICAL DISCUSSION. I JUST WANT SUGGESTION OF POSSIBLE WORDS + EXPLANATION. THANK YOU.**

Comment: 'Boundless' or 'limitless' work for both time (eternal) and space (infinite). I can see however that they work for everything and you would prefer it constrained to only time and space.

Comment: In future, please don't post a new question when [one gets put on hold](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/414785/is-there-a-word-which-means-not-bound-by-time-or-space). Edit that question to bring it on-topic — this puts it into a review queue for re-opening. This helps future visitors by not duplicating questions, and helps you avoid a potential system-generated ban because of old off-topic questions. Deleting these abandoned questions doesn't change the behaviour of the ban algorithm: questions on hold need to be improved.

Comment: space-timeless?

Comment: Indeterminate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about "universal"?

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/universal

> adjective
>   2.
>   applicable everywhere or in all cases; general:

It's not explicitly stated in that definition (maybe it's covered by 'in all cases'), but I think "universal" can mean "in all times" as well as "in all places".

Comment: Since the OP doesn't like _eternal_ (which would have been my first choice, as to me it has enough _implication_ of not bound in space to do the job), then I think this is probably the best... _across the universe of time and space_.

Comment: I also think "eternal" is the best answer, as to say that the question is asked in every place as well (presumably by billions of alien species) seems a bit presumptive to say the least.  Plus the phrase "eternal question" is well known to mean "a question that has been asked countless times and will continue to be asked in the future".

Comment: I was about to add it as an answer (including the commonality of the phrase "_eternal question_") when I noticed they'd rejected it.

Comment: Yeah.  Asking us to not have a philosophical discussion is a bit pointless as well, eh.   I mean where's the fun in that?  That's why I signed up!

Comment: Thank you so much guys! I am currently considering both "universal" and "eternal." (And please no philosophical discussion :D haha )

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want something like **boundless** or **illimitable**, though these terms do not imply by what measure.
**Godlike** is an alternative, but it also implies omnipotentence alongside omnipresence and timelessness.
I would suggest that **all-pervasive** might work best though, and I think will suit your sentence.

> present or noticeable in every part of a thing or place http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pervasive

Answer (score -1):

**Indefinite** implies that there aren't any clear boundaries. It's not bound to either space or time.

As a reference, this is the [Cambridge Dictionary's definition for indefinite](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/indefinite) .

Comment: 'Indefinite' also implies that the question is not clear, when read in context with the OP's question: The purpose of my research aims to solve and answer this 'indefinite' question.

Comment: I can't upvote your comment, but you're right. I had not thought of the adjective making the question seem unclear.